# Configuring survey design for multilevel modeling with National Inpatient Sample

Tags: sampling, stata, survey

I am a researcher looking to use multilevel mixed-effects models in Stata 14 to analyze the National Inpatient Sample. I am aware that the typical way that you configure the NIS' survey design for analysis is:

```
svyset [pw=DISCWT], strata(NIS_STRATUM) psu(HOSPID)
```

However, whenever I create the survey design in this way, I get thrown an error 
when running meglm that says:

"survey final weights not allowed with multilevel models;

a final weight variable was svyset using the [pw=exp] syntax, but multilevel models require that each stage-level weight variable is svyset using the stage's
    corresponding weight() option"

What is the proper way that I should set use svyset to set up multiple-stage design in order to use methods like meglm? Thank you!